# SSMTP - Can send E-Mail via CLI - But Programs fail to send notifications

Tags: mail-command, ssmtp

Today I set up a new XYMon monitor VM. **The old one used PostFix, but I set up SSMTP.**

**I can e-mail myself fine from the CLI** like such.

```
echo "Hello, World" | mail -s "My email check" my@email.com
```

But I **can't seem to get XYMon to notify me via E-Mail**.

I have done a few tests, I'm suspecting this is **related to SSMTP more the XYMon** as its fairly simple to set up.

```
/usr/lib/xymon/server/bin/xymond_alert --test testsite.com http
```

**Results in this line :** (Among many others, but this is the important one)

```
 Mail alert with command '/var/mail/root "Xymon [12345] testsite.com:http CRITICAL (RED)" accountusername@businessdomain.com'
```

There are a few things wrong with this, first there is no /var/mail/root that I can find, also, accountusername@businessdomain.com is the username I authenticate with and configure SSMTP with, but not the e-mail I actually want this notification sent to.

**My SSMTP Configs :**

```
mailhub=smtp.comcast.net:587
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
hostname=businessdomain.com
AuthUser=accountusername@businessdomain.com
AuthPass=PASSWORD
```

**My Alerts in XYMon :**

```
HOST=testsite.com
MAIL my@email.com REPEAT=1h COLOR=red DURATION>15 RECOVERED
```

**UPDATE**

```
# For the xymond_alert module
MAILC="mail"                            # Command used to send an e-mail with no subject
MAIL="$MAILC -s"                                # Command used to send an e-mail with a subject

root@monitor:/etc/xymon# echo $MAIL
/var/mail/root
```

Comment: Did you define the `MAIL` setting in `xymonserver.cfg` ?  If not then it may default to the `$MAIL` environment variable, which could easily be `/var/mail/root` for the root user since that is the default mailbox for root's email.  http://xymon.sourceforge.net/xymon/help/manpages/man5/xymonserver.cfg.5.html

Comment: Perhaps I need to export the variable? or change it system wide?

Comment: Just try `unset MAIL`...

Comment: That worked! - Should I Change question to be specific to XYMon? Or leave as is? You can write an answer and I'd accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is in how XYmon determines what mailer to use.  It can use the `MAIL` setting or it can use the `$MAIL` variable.

Now the default `$MAIL` setting for `root` is `/var/mail/root` and so it will try and *execute* that as if it was a command.

You can fix this by unsetting the environment variable

```
unset MAIL
```

This will ensure XYmon just uses its configuration and isn't overridden by the environment.